# Download Blogspot blog in HTML

Tags: blogger

Is there a way to download an entire Blogspot blog in HTML format, without the ads and associated cruft?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download an entire website?](http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Comment: Are you the owner of the blog to be downloaded?

Answer (score 6):

Just my two cents ... [Winhttrack](http://www.httrack.com/)?

Comment: Well, I usually use this application to download from Artofmanliness and such blogs. Saves the site completely, so I have a browsable archive on my laptop ... I can read useful stuff on the bus/train. :))

Comment: Any advice how to configure it to go around "content warning" no blogs that require to click "I agree" ?

Answer (score 3):

Perl has several good modules for doing this.

LWP:
Mechanize:

Both can be found on http://search.cpan.org

From the command line, when this tool is called, you can recursively grab all files in the directory by typing `wget -r sitename`.

Wget: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

As for out of the box software that you can use on a GUI, I am of no help.

Answer (score 1):

For the owners of the blog... Google provides the functionality to download the entire blog (posts, comments, the whole nine yards).

http://www.dataliberation.org/google/blogger

In case of content from other people's blog, copyright violation comes into the picture.

Answer (score -2):

Use an adblocker add-on in your browser to remove the ads.

Then, use the "save as" feature in your browser to save the page in HTML.

Comment: I guess he means downloading the *whole* blog.

Comment: Yes I do. This blog has 2,578 posts. :-) I'm not doing them all by hand.